# Cannot find central directory error

Tags: c#

I am trying to read data from an excel file.

```
FileStream stream = File.Open (@"C:\Temp\F1\SMRPAC974-00024COMINVDETEXTRACT.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
DataSet result = excelReader.AsDataSet();
excelReader.Close();
string csvData = "";
int row_no = 0;
while (row_no < result.Tables[0].Rows.Count)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < result.Tables[0].Columns.Count; i++)
 {
  csvData += result.Tables[0].Rows[row_no][i].ToString() + ";";
 }
 row_no++;
 csvData += "\n";
}
```

The problem i'm currently tackling with is an error that "Cannot find central directory". I don't know what this means I have even tried moving the excel file to different locations but i'm still facing the same error.

Comment: Could you provide a stacktrace?

Comment: Could it be that the file is corrupt?

Comment: Considering that a .xlsx file is basically a zipped xml file and the error seems to indicate a problem with zip files, I'd assume a corrupt file.

Comment: "Central Directory" in this context likely refers to the fact that `.xlsx` format Excel files are essentially ZIP files. A ZIP file contains a Central Directory which I *think* lists the files that are present. This error message means that one of the following is true: (1) the file is corrupt, (2) the file is not actually an `.xslx` file (are you sure it isn't an `.xls` file?) or (3) the library you're using to read the file has a bug

Comment: @TreviAwater i dont know what you are talking about

Comment: oh is an xlsx like a zipped file there? If so then yes gerald is completely correct there. For a zipped file if THAT error occurs then the folder name which is stored at the end of a zip file is corrupted

Comment: @Rob tried reading it in .xls file too

Comment: @TheBells did you try it also with a different xlsx/xls file? that way you can rule out that your library is at fault. if that works either the file is not what it seems to be or it is corrupted

Comment: @Thomas tried it with other files and it worked so i think it is safe to say that it is corrupt

Answer (score 18, accepted):

An exception stating:

> Cannot find central directory

indicates that one of the following is likely true:

1. The file is corrupt
2. The file is not actually an `.xlsx` file (are you sure it isn't an `.xls` file?)
3. The library you're using to read the file has a bug

From your code it looks like you're using [ExcelDataReader](https://github.com/ExcelDataReader/ExcelDataReader) and attempting to open an XML format (`xlsx`) file. Are you *sure* that the file isn't actually a `.xls` file that someone has mis-named as `.xlsx`? You could check this by using:

```
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
```

instead of:

```
IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

Answer (score 2):

check weather you are using .xlsx or .xls file.

If you are using .xlsx then use

```
     IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateOpenXmlReader(stream);
```

if you are using .xls then use

```
    IExcelDataReader excelReader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateBinaryReader(stream);
```

Hope it helps. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will also receive this error if the Excel file is password protected.